# What attaches plant cells to the cell wall?

Tags: proteins, cell-membrane, plant-anatomy, eukaryotic-cells

In animal cells integrins span the plasma membrane and attach the cell membrane to the extracellular matrix. I was wondering how are plant cells attached to the cell wall? Is it just the middle lamella holding them in place or is there something else (i.e proteins)?